# How to extract text from starting keyword upto the next capital letter word using regex

Tags: python-3.x

```
import re
a = "This is a Feedback: Note: We have written this Feedback: The product is good. Very output is valid."
x = re.findall("(?:(?:Feedback:[^.]*.))", a)
print(x)
Required solution: The product is good.
```

Starting keyword = "Feedback:" Is there any solution to extract text in between starting keyword to the next capital letter "Note:" and "Very"

Comment: What if you have a feedback "The product Car is good." Should we go to very or stop at Car?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this.

```
=MID(A1,SEARCHB(":",A1,(SEARCHB(":",A1,(SEARCHB(":",A1,1)+1))+1)+1)+2,FIND(".",A1,1)-SEARCHB(":",A1,(SEARCHB(":",A1,(SEARCHB(":",A1,1)+1))+1)+1)*1)
```

[image]